# Unity 5.5 layers

Tags: unity-game-engine, layer

I have a question regarding panels/layers in Unity.
My problem is that sprite which i set to be in the lowest layer, overlaps other panels which are set to be in higher levels. Is there any way to fix it? I tried almost everything and still my sprite is always overlaping layers which are above it. 
[image: overlaping]

in the next picture you can see settings of the layers. 
[image: dosage layer]

[image: reward layer]

I would really appreciate a help. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You Can just re-order them in the Hierarchy window. top to bottom. Bottom most is above everything else.
There are other posts on this subject you can check. But you need to use transform [SetAsFirstSibling](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetAsFirstSibling.html), [SetAsLastSibling](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetAsLastSibling.html), [SetSiblingIndex](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetSiblingIndex.html), [GetSiblingIndex](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetSiblingIndex.html)

Please take a look at [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/806928/new-ui-how-to-change-depthorder-from-script.html)